# MPI libraries not found from gfortran using CMake

Tags: cmake, fortran, mpi, gfortran

I am moving the first steps with CMake and I am currently trying to compile a simple test program called "test_cmake" to be linked against MPI. The CMake build went fine but "Make" gives me the following errors:

```
gfortran: error: /home/edo/software/openmpi-4.1.1/build/lib64/libmpi_usempif08.so;/home/edo/software/openmpi-4.1.1/build/lib64/libmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr.so;/home/edo/software/openmpi-4.1.1/build/lib64/libmpi_mpifh.so;/home/edo/software/openmpi-4.1.1/build/lib64/libmpi.so: No such file or directory
```

Mpi libraries are all there, I am wondering if the ";" is messing up gfortran (10.2).

My CMakeLists is the following:

```
# CMake project file for TEST

# PROJECT
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (TEST)
enable_language (Fortran)


# Additional variables

set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules/")

set (FLUBIO_SRC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sources")
set (FLUBIO_SOLVERS_SRC "${FLUBIO_SRC}/solvers")

# Compilers flag
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -cpp -mcmodel=medium -fdefault-real-8 -ffree-line-length-512 -ffast-math")
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG  "-Og -g -cpp -mcmodel=medium -fdefault-real-8 -fcheck=all -ffree-line-length-512")

# Find required libraries
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
find_package(PETSc REQUIRED)

message("===========================================")
message(${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH})


# Targets

set (TARGETS "test_cmake")

add_executable(${TARGETS} "${FLUBIO_SOLVERS_SRC}/test_cmake.f90")

# Target properties
#MPI_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS

set_target_properties(${TARGETS} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE})

#add mpi lib
add_library(mpi SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(mpi PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES}" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH}")
target_link_libraries(${TARGETS} mpi)
```

Thank you for all the valuable help you can give me.

Comment: For IMPORTED target the property [IMPORTED_LOCATION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) should contain **exactly one** library. So assigning to that property a value `${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES}`, which contains *several* libraries, is **wrong**. If you want to create a target which wraps *several* libraries, then you could create INTERFACE library target and assign its [INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html) property.

Comment: I see, sorry it was indeed a silly question, but happy you pointed me out in the right direction.